# How to display ViewPager title?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi i have to implement `ViewPager` in my app. here i have to load `ImageAdapter` that extends `PagerAdapter` and i successfully see all the images into viewpager.

Now, i want to display viewpager title as my image counter.

**Layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_ig" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please some one give me information how i want to do that!

Comment: need to add `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip` into your `layout` and override `CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` method in your `Adapter`

Comment: @SimplePlan give me some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need to add `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip` into your `Layout.xml` file like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/gallery_detail_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_ig" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pts_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, override  `CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` method int you `Adapter` like:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

     ............ 
     @Override
     public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
         return (position + 1);
         }
    ...........
}
```

And implement into your `PagerTabStrip` like: you can customized `PagerTabStrip` options

```
PagerTabStrip strip = (PagerTabStrip)view.findViewById(R.id.pts_main);
strip.setDrawFullUnderline(false);
strip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.DKGRAY);
strip.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
strip.setNonPrimaryAlpha(0.5f);
strip.setTextSpacing(25);
strip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
```

Comment: @SP OMG! it's easy to implement but i have no idea about this. work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

add a **PagerTitleStrip** in **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pgrStrp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in **PageAdapter.java**  add the following method:

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Title Here";
    }
```

Comment: OMG! it's very easy to implement. work like a charm!

Comment: :)
So you come out from your problem !